# How to make the field name case incensitive in an nhibernate.search query

Tags: lucene.net, nhibernate.search

I would like to make the field name in my query case incesitive so that when users make the queries

```
title:Jurassic
```

or

```
Title:Jurassic
```

NHibernate Search would yield the same result.

As I understand the way Lucene works field names are case sensitive. Is there a way to configure NH Search/Lucene to lowercase the field names when indexing and lowercase the fieldname when searching?

Answer (score 1):

Field names are case sensitive. One way is to specify all of your fields to be completely lowercase and then lowercase your query.

class example:

```
[Indexed]
class Article
{
     [Field(Name="title", Index=Index.Tokenized, Store=Store.No)]
     Title { get; set; }
}
```

query example

```
string query = tbSearch.Text;
query = query.ToLower();
IFullTextQuery ftq = search.CreateFullTextQuery(query);
```

Comment: I knew I could always lowercase everything. I was just wondering if thhere were some automatic way to configure the query parser to match fields in a case insensitive way.

Comment: I think the best way to handle that is to look into building your own QueryParser. Lucene.Net comes with a MultiFieldQueryParser. I think checking out the source code to this class will help you understand what it takes to build a custom QueryParser.

Comment: Be careful, the QueryParser wouldn't recognize Operators anymore, since all Operators like AND/OR/NOT/TO have to be uppercase